# cdto (to open a terminal) does not work in Mavericks

Tags: macos, terminal

I've just switched to the Mavericks operating system in my Mac. I used to utilize a quite nice app called "cdto" that serves to open a terminal at the current directory where Finder is. The point is that now "cdto" does not seem to work with Mavericks.
Before I used to utilize "OpenTerminalHere" but it is now obsolete.

Anyone with the same problem and any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Please download the latest version at :
https://github.com/jbtule/cdto/releases

**Note:** on Marvericks, you need to hold down the Command Key to drag the `cdto.app` into the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had any issues with it since upgrading to Mavericks. What version are you using and what happens when you open it?

The latest, **2.5** (signed for Gatekeeper compatibility), appears to work. You can download it here: https://code.google.com/p/cdto/downloads/detail?name=cdto_2.5_sign.zip

Answer (score 0):

I think I was doing something wrong.
It is necessary to hold on the command key before dragging the app to the Finder toolbar.
Thanks for the help.